# What is the difference between :while and :when in clojure?

Tags: for-loop, clojure

I'm studying clojure but not quite clear on the difference between the `:while` and `:when` test:

```
=> (for [x [1 2 3] y [1 2 3] :while (= (mod x y) 0)] [x y])
([1 1] [2 1] [2 2] [3 1])
=> (for [x [1 2 3] y [1 2 3] :when (= (mod x y) 0)] [x y])
([1 1] [2 1] [2 2] [3 1] [3 3])
```

Can anybody help by elaborating on them ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`:when` iterates over the bindings, but only evaluates the body of the loop when the condition is true. `:while` iterates over the bindings and evaluates the body *until* the condition is false:

```
(for [x (range 20) :when (not= x 10)] x)
; =>(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19)

(for [x (range 20) :while (not= x 10)] x)
; => (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: Note, you can use (not= x 10) instead of (not (= x 10)), if preferred.

Answer (score 8):

:when prevents any inner 'for' bindings or its body expression from being evaluated for that one iteration, acting like the 'filter' function.

:while halts this binding from proceeding any more, acting more like 'take-while'

Answer (score 1):

Look at the last example here:
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for#example_913

Comment: Which one? Could you copy it inside your answer ?