# For loop in clojure

Tags: for-loop, clojure

```
    n = (count somevector)        
   (foo [w] ( for [i (range n) 
                   j (range w)
                   :let [n (* i j)] 
                   :while ( < i j)
                  ] 
              (println n)))
```

When i run it.

=> (foo 10)
`ClassCastException` `clojure`.`lang`.`LazySeq` cannot be cast to `clojure`.`lang`.`IFn`  HelloWorld.core/foo

What I am really looking to do is have a couple of nested for loops and have some ifs and else inside it do some checking.

Edit ::

As it turns out the following also causes error

```
(defn foo [arg]
 (      
      for [ i (range (count vector)) ]
      (
        for [j arg ]
        [i j]
        ) 

     ) )
```

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom

Edit::

the following works

```
(defn foo [arg]
  (def w arg) 
(for [ i (range (count vector)) ]
      (
        for [j (range v)  ]
        [i j]
        )
  )   )
```

Now can someone help me understand why would it not work in the first place ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom

This error message states the cause of exception accurately.
I guess you passed a `long` value where a `seq` is expected.
I could reproduce it:

```
user> (def v [1 2 3])
#'user/v
user> (defn foo [arg]
        (for [ i (range (count v)) ]
             (for [j arg ]
                  [i j]))) 
#'user/foo
user> (foo (range 3))
(([0 0] [0 1] [0 2]) ([1 0] [1 1] [1 2]) ([2 0] [2 1] [2 2]))
user> (foo 3)
; Evaluation aborted.
; Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
;  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

Your `foo` function works. However, the `arg` argument must be a `seq`,
because `arg` is binded in the nested `for` to `j`

Comment: for [ j (range arg)] should fix this .

Answer (score 7):

if you use `:while`, `for-loop` will return null, because first value is false,  `:when` is better.

```
user=> (for [i (range 3) j (range 5)] [i j])
([0 0] [0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4] [1 0] [1 1] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [2 0] [2 1] [2 2] [2 3] [2 4])
user=> (for [i (range 3) j (range 5) :while (< i j)] [i j])
()
user=> (for [i (range 3) j (range 5) :when (< i j)] [i j])
([0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [2 3] [2 4])
```

Comment: what is the difference between :while and :when in clojure： http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966142/what-is-the-difference-between-while-and-when-in-clojure

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should know is, that clojure's `for` is not a for loop, it's a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension).

This means, that it is used to build lists (lazy sequence, actually) with the specified properties.

Your original `for` looks like this:

```
(for [i (range n) 
      j (range w)
      :let [n (* i j)] 
      :while ( < i j)] 
  (println n))
```

(I don't get a class cast exception with your original example).

What it says is: take pairs of `i` and `j` while `i < j` do something. The first pair of `i` and `j` is `i = 0` and `j = 0`. Is 0 < 0? No. Stop. That is, you're constructing an empty sequence.

Now, if we change the `:while` with `:when`, it'll change the meaning to: for each pair of `i` and `j`, for which `i < j`, and do something with them. That is, you won't stop constructing the sequence when you encounter an i >= j, you'll just skip this pair.

The next thing to note is the `println`. This function prints its arguments, but always returns `nil`.  This return value is what you'll get in the result sequence and the printing is called a side effect. Generally, you don't want side effect with lazy sequences, because they (the side effects) will happen when needed. That is, if you assign the returned sequence to some variable, none of the `println`s will be called. They'll start popping up, when the sequence gets *realized*.

The bottom line is, don't think of `for` as a loop, think of it as a sequence constructor.

Comment: This was interesting ... so how do we realise a sequence in functional sense ? so, if I return instead of printing does that mean it will realised ?

Comment: You "realize" a sequence by requesting its elements. It'll be realized to the point it's needed. For example `(take 10 (range))` will return only the first 10 integers of the infinite sequence generated by `range`. (Actually `take` is also lazy, but the REPL isn't, so it forces the realization.) You can also force realization explicitly with `doall` or `dorun` (they differ in what they return). Also related is `doseq`.

Comment: Also, "traditional" looping is done with `loop` and `recur`, but these are often considered low-level building blocks for creating higher level abstractions, like `map`, `filter`, `for`, etc.